# Is there a way to auto-include a file into all source files in C++/C#?

Tags: c++, include

I've been periodically in the position to need to include a single file with my own definitions and other frequent code into every other source file.
From what I know, MSVS 2013 as well as other compilers allows easy inclusion of multiple files into one but haven't seen easy inclusion of one file into multiple ones.
Currently I have to manually include the frequent code file in dozens of files for which reason I consider myself ignorant.
There has to be a way to specify "global" files, visible from anywhere. And thinking about the fact that the compiler/linker sweeps through all cpp's in the project anyway...
EDIT:
As per a comment below, how can "force include", as in `-include` argument for GCC, be achieved in MSVS?

Comment: `-include` is the GCC option for forcing an include (and presumably clang too).

Comment: how about editing your templates for classes.

Comment: @user657267 Thanks. I can't find any related options in the project properties, I don't know where to look.

Comment: @Shoaib it seems more like a workaround than a obvious solution.

Comment: @mireazma that's why i made it a comment

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is... you should include what you use when and if you use it. That is part of the design. Are you concerned about having to type `#include <file.h>` multiple times? Are you including it only when you need it?

Comment: Just write some editor script to do the job (on POSIX systems, you could use `sed` or `ed`; I am sure your OS has something equivalent)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas well, that's the point: I need it in 80% of the files and it's a 20 line file. So what user657267 suggested is perfect but I don't know how to do it in MSVS.

Comment: @mireazma: I would not follow that path, it means that the source code is no longer sufficient to correctly build your project. The source code becomes invalid and is *fixed* by the compiler injecting additional things (forced includes). Honestly, just copy and paste the include to those files that need it. How many files are 80% of your project? 8? 40? 80? This should not be a common operation, if you end up doing this more than once or twice you should start reconsidering your design process...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I have type definitions and functions that I use throughout the project over and over. Pardon me but repetitive code, even in this case, is not the right way; I tend to code in a way that it's easier to maintain and have as few bloat lines as I can. Let's say it's not a sign of elegant style to type `#include"file.h"` 20 times out of 25 and hunt down where you use the definitions and where you dropped them and add/delete the culprit line...

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio *and* you are using precompiled headers, then include your special header file in the `stdafx.h` file (or whatever you designate for the precompiled header).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found exactly what I needed here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c5ztk84.aspx
I tested it and commented out `#include`'s of the `Definitions.hpp`, i.e. the frequently used code and it doesn't show any error.
Thank you for your time and ideas though.